# How to write single class based view for multiple url?

Tags: python, django

I have urls ***reporting?id=1*** and ***reporting?students=bachelor***. For both these urls I am using same base url 'reporting' in urls.py.

**urls.py**

```
from .views import Reporting

urlpatterns = [
    path('', AnalyticsData.as_view()),
    path('reporting', Reporting.as_view()),
    path('index', index.as_view())
]
```

How could I use the same class view to execute different get methods so that for the first URL, a method to get students by id is executed and for the second URL, a method to get bachelor students is executed. For now, I am writing code in the following way

**views.py**

```
class Reporting(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        id = self.request.GET.get("id")
        student_type = self.request.GET.get("students")

        if id:
            *logic*
        if student_type=="bachelor":
            *logic*
```

But I don't know if this is the right way. Also, if there are multiple parameters than there will be many if conditions. Is there any other way available?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a variable in my class based view that tells what to do when it is called. Something like this. This `var` variable gets the value of whatever that is passed when calling it from the `urls.py` so you can use that to your advantage.

```
class Reporting(APIView):

    var = "" # HERE

    def get(self, request):

        id = self.request.GET.get("id")
        student_type = self.request.GET.get("students")

        if id:
            *logic*
        if student_type=="bachelor":
            *logic*
```

Then in my `urls.py` I would call the class with that parameter and handle the logic accordingly.

```
from .views import Reporting

urlpatterns = [
    path('reporting', Reporting.as_view(var="yourvalue")), #HERE
]
```

Then handle logic according to the `var` variable. 
So now if you want your class to behave differently for another case, then you can change `var` variable accordingly and the behaviour would also change. You just need to change the value in your url.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('reporting', Reporting.as_view(var="yourvalue")), #HERE
    path('new_reporting', Reporting.as_view(var="your_new_value"))
]
```

So for your case you can pass this `var` along to your views and then you can use `if else` to process the `get` function. *Don't forget the `self` btw*.

```
if self.var == "id":
    # Logic for id
elif self.var == "students":
    # Logic for students
```

Comment: yes then in your `get` method you can use `if` to check value of `var` and run the block of code accordingly. `if var == "id": #logic for id , else: #logic for student`

Comment: Do not forget to add `self.` btw.

Comment: this is such a dumb workaround, i should be able to have separate functions for this purpose